# Содержимое вкладок исчезает после перезагрузки фрагмента (Android Studio Java)

Tags: java, android, android-tabs

Я хотел сделать вкладки с [этим ответом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23678630/12756021). Все скопировал и запустил. При первой загрузки фрагмента, в котором есть вкладки, все нормально. Только когда я перезапускаю фрагмент (меняю тему приложения, перехожу на вторую страницу) все внезапно исчезает, и в консоли появляется ошибка о том, что MainActivity не может найти представления и изменить текст. Понятия не имею, почему это происходит. Помогите мне, пожалуйста.

**fragment_user.xml:**

```
<TabHost
      android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleProfile">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

      <TabWidget
          android:id="@android:id/tabs"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="0"
          android:orientation="horizontal" />

      <FrameLayout
          android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="0" />

      <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
          android:id="@+id/pager"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
  </TabHost>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
try{
    TextView orderText = findViewById(R.id.orderText);
    TextView datecreated = findViewById(R.id.orderDateCreated);
    datecreated.setText(...);
    orderText.setText(...);
    findViewById(R.id.noneOrdersFrame).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.yourOrdersText).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.orderFrame).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.profileLoadingTxt).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}catch (Exception e){
    Log.e("error",e.toString());
}
```

**UserFragment.java:**

```
private TabHost mTabHost;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;

public UserFragment() { }

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle instance) {
  super.onCreate(instance);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user, container, false);

  mTabHost = v.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
  mTabHost.setup();

  mViewPager = v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
  mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(getActivity(), mTabHost, mViewPager);

  mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("one").setIndicator("Мой заказ"), TabOrder.class, null);
  mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("two").setIndicator("История"), TabHistory.class, null);

  return v;
}

public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
  private final Context mContext;
  private final TabHost mTabHost;
  private final ViewPager mViewPager;
  private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

  static final class TabInfo {
    private final String tag;
    private final Class<?> clss;
    private final Bundle args;

    TabInfo(String _tag, Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
      tag = _tag;
      clss = _class;
      args = _args;
    }
  }

  static class DummyTabFactory implements TabHost.TabContentFactory {
    private final Context mContext;

    public DummyTabFactory(Context context)
    {
      mContext = context;
    }

    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
      View v = new View(mContext);
      v.setMinimumWidth(0);
      v.setMinimumHeight(0);
      return v;
    }
  }

  public TabsAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, ViewPager pager) {
    super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
    mContext = activity;
    mTabHost = tabHost;
    mViewPager = pager;
    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
  }

  public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
    tabSpec.setContent(new DummyTabFactory(mContext));
    String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

    TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);
    mTabs.add(info);
    mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount()
  {
    return mTabs.size();
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);

    return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
  }

  public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    int position = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
  }

  public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) { }

  public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    TabWidget widget = mTabHost.getTabWidget();
    int oldFocusability = widget.getDescendantFocusability();
    widget.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
    widget.setDescendantFocusability(oldFocusability);
  }

  public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) { }
}
```

**TabOrder.java:**

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_order, container, false);
    return root;
}
```

Comment: Приведите код Mainactivity. И сделайте код объявления данных в onResume

Comment: @ArtyMorris Извините, но я не совсем понял, что нужно сделать. И еще у меня возник вопрос, как мне найти view в viewpager. Отредактируйте мой код и отправьте ответ. Если все сработает, то я отмечу его как ответ.